# How to debug xslt code from DSpace Mirage 2 theme in IntelliJ?

Tags: xslt, intellij-idea, dspace, apache-cocoon

I use IntelliJ 2017 and DSpace 6, and I can debug Java code successfully, but I can not debug code from the xslt files of the Mirage 2 theme. How to debug xslt code from DSpace Mirage 2 theme in IntelliJ?

Comment: I have a test instance of DSpace, so I generally test XSLT changes directly on the test server.  If you add a URL parameter of XML to a page request, you can save the raw XML for a page locally.  See http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/handle/10673/6?XML

Answer (score 0):

To debug XSLT files in IntelliJ, you have some options. (note that this is not a DSpace specific answer, but rather an XSLT-specific answer).

If you are using a relatively new version of IntelliJ, you actually have an XSLT debugger that you can configure, this is explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/run-debug-configuration-xslt.html).
This can provide you with some debugging capabilities like the use of evaluating expression on a currently running "document" as you would with Java.

## (older IntelliJ versions)

If you are using an older version of IntelliJ and XSLT 1.0, you could use this [XSLT-Debugger plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1818-xslt-debugger).